# Can access URL on Android device from browser, cannot access from app

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I'm trying to login to a server using HttpPost (testing on my HTC One V). I get

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /121.241.197.102:15500 timed out
```

But weirdly it can access it fine from the phone's browser. I have 3G connection and I can access the URL from browser within a second and I've set timeout params to 20 seconds.

Code I use to connect:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 200000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 200000);
        httpClient= new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        CookieStore cookieStore = httpClient.getCookieStore();
        if(cookies.size()>0)
            for(int i=0;i<cookies.size();i++)
                cookieStore.addCookie(cookies.get(i));
        httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieStore); 
        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        InputStream inputStream=null;
        try{
            HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost(url);
            StringEntity se=new StringEntity(input.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

The connection fails when I try to execute(httpPost). On emulator I try this with the exact same code and a local network IP, it works perfectly with same code. Problem arises when I use public IP and real device. Any solutions?

**EDIT**
Here is LogCat

```
06-19 10:47:44.559: W/System.err(2466): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /121.241.197.102:15500 timed out
06-19 10:47:44.569: W/System.err(2466):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
06-19 10:47:44.569: W/System.err(2466):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-19 10:47:44.569: W/System.err(2466):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-19 10:47:44.569: W/System.err(2466):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-19 10:47:44.569: W/System.err(2466):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-19 10:47:44.569: W/System.err(2466):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-19 10:47:44.589: W/System.err(2466):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-19 10:47:44.589: W/System.err(2466):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-19 10:47:44.589: W/System.err(2466):     at com.ambr.tradeapp.utility.JSONConnectorPost.connectClient(JSONConnectorPost.java:66)
06-19 10:47:44.589: W/System.err(2466):     at com.ambr.tradeapp.activity.MainActivity$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:82)
06-19 10:47:44.589: W/System.err(2466):     at com.ambr.tradeapp.activity.MainActivity$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-19 10:47:44.599: W/System.err(2466):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-19 10:47:44.599: W/System.err(2466):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-19 10:47:44.599: W/System.err(2466):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-19 10:47:44.599: W/System.err(2466):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-19 10:47:44.599: W/System.err(2466):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-19 10:47:44.599: W/System.err(2466):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Please show how the content of url looks like. Does the device use wifi or 3G?

Comment: post your logcat please :D

Comment: @greenapps Content as in the response I am supposed to get? I get a Json response, for this case something like 
{"_returnValue":true,"FORCE_PASSWORD_CHANGE":"FALSE","_returnType":"SUCCESS"}

Comment: No. What is the url? I would like to see if you made syntax errors or so. How do you call the site? Your code is in a thread or asynctask?

Comment: I get url with getString(R.string.login_url) and it i defined in strings.xml as http://121.241.197.102:15500/Trade/mdi/html/desktop/AJAXHandler.jsp

Comment: You posted it in such a way that we cannot see the leading http:// Is it there?

Comment: The target URL in the error looks dodgy.  Do you have the leading `http://` or `https://`?  what is the full URL - from your source code or config file?

Comment: This thing keeps removing the http and posting as hyperlink -_- there is http:// before 121.241....

Comment: I see already it is there and the url functions. So this a strange problem.

Comment: @greenapps I know it is very strange. This app has worked for me for the past 2-3 weeks I've been working on it on emulator. So I'm sure it's not some silly error like missing http or missing internet permission.

Comment: Plaese post a relevant part of the stacktrace/logcat. Is your code in a thread or asynctask?

Comment: @greenapps added LogCat in Edit, Sorry I forgot to post it before. It is in an AsyncTask. Also if I check the response code I get 0. I suppose that is just because it could not conenct.

Comment: With the phones browser you did a GET? Or just url without parameters? In your android you do a login post. Mmmm we can talk a lot about this but best thing to do for you first is obtaining another device somewhere to see if it is HTC.

Comment: @greenapps In phone browser I just checked if I could access the site, by just going to http://121.241.197.102:15500/Trade

Comment: You said you used 3G. Try with wifi.

Comment: @greenapps It works now, I didn't change anything and I'm still using 3G, I don't know why.